# Displaying an editable custom database in wp dashboard

Tags: javascript, php, sql, wordpress, dashboard

I would like to add in the submenu of my plugin the option of displaying a table of people registered for an event with the possibility of searching rows by last name, time and/or event name (in various combinations, e.g. by the name of the event, or by name and time ...). I would also need the option of accepting or rejecting a person and the possibility of changing his data or deleting it.

I tried to find some examples, but I couldn't find anything meaningful, so could someone here post a link to a page where similar things are described, or send here some sample codes that I could based on?

Have a nice day!

Comment: Its abit confusing what you are asking.  We have events which i assume are custom post type where you have lists of registered users with some data per user. The problem that i see is if its data like First name for example and you want to edit it will update the First name of the user for all events that he is singed in right? What i would do is per event to store each user and its data as meta and my table will be list of events and with ajax to pull all users from it and edit/update from there. Will be more efficiant and fast approach to me. For sorting columns there are planty of examples.

Comment: there is only one table with columns (event name, name, surname, time of the event). Two same people cannot sign up for the same event

Comment: But same person can sign for different events was my point. And showing same person multiple times but for different event its not very effective approach to me.

Comment: ok, but it will be a totally differentrow, and I don't want an edit function, for example a last name, only an edit option, as it is in the database, only edits values from a given row
Somenthing like comments tab

Comment: If anyone is still interested in this post, I found a solution to my problem its WP_List_Table function, and tutorial: [link](https://onlinewebtutorblog.com/wordpress-table/bind-data-from-database/)